# return $this->redirect()->toRoute() doesn't work in zend framework

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, zend-framework2

My problem is so small but I didn't found a solution. I use doctrine with Zend Framework 2 and the problem occurs when I flush my data to the database I want to redirect to `blog` route. It isn't working.
This is my action :

```
public function addAction()
{
    if ($this->request->isPost()) 
    {
        $article = new Article();
        $article->setTitle($this->getRequest()->getPost('title'));
        $article->setDate(new \DateTime());
        $article->setContent($this->getRequest()->getPost('content'));
        $article->setPublication($this->getRequest()->getPost('publication'));

        $this->getObjectManager()->persist($article);
        $this->getObjectManager()->flush();
        $newId = $article->getId();

        return $this->redirect()->toRoute('blog');
    }
    return new ViewModel();
}
```

and this is my view :

```
<form class="contact_form" method="post" >
    <ul>
        <li>
            <h2>Add Article</h2>
            <span class="required_notification">* Required Field</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>Publication:</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="publication" required />
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>Title:</label>
            <input type="text" name="title" required />
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>Date:</label>
            <input type="date" name="date" name="date" required />
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>Content:</label>
            <textarea name="content" cols="40" rows="6" required ></textarea>
        </li>
        <li>
            <button class="submit" type="submit">Add</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

finally this is my route :

```
'add' => array(
    'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
    'options' => array(
        'route'    => '/blog/article/add',
        'defaults' => array(
            'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Blog',
            'action'     => 'add',
        ),
    ),
),
'defaults' => array(
    '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
    'controller'    => 'Blog',
    'action'        => 'add',
),
'template_map' => array(
    'layout/layout'        => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
    'application/blog/add' => __DIR__ . '/../view/application/blog/add.phtml',
    'error/404'            => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
    'error/index'          => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
),
```

When I press Add button the data added correctly to the database but doesn't redirect to the my blog route. This is a image from what I got:

[image]

Comment: Is your webserver even running? Check if the route exists. And please learn with the ZF2 Documentation. Your code is highly insecure.

Comment: yes i am a beginner in zend, the code is insecure ? where exactly !! yes webserver is running fine

Comment: @Mohammadov:: Sam is right, where are the form validations?? Remember one thing, `Never trust User Input!!`

Answer (score 1):

There is no route named `blog` in your config.

You must specify a route named `blog` as in this example :

```
<?php
return array(
    'routes' => array(
        'home' => array(
            'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index',
                    'action' => 'index',
                ),
            ),
        ),
        'blog' => array(
            'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/blog',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Blog',
                    'action' => 'index',
                ),
            ),
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => array(
                'add' => array(
                    'type' => 'Literal',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route' => '/article/add',
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Blog',
                            'action' => 'add',
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

Plus, you should confgure your php.ini with display_errors = ON to easily debug your problems.

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
 $this->redirect()->toRoute('blog');
 $this->getResponse()->sendHeaders();
 exit();
```

The *toRoute()* method in Zend Framework 2 just seems to setup the redirect headers but doesn't actually send them to the browser.